# How to register a service too ZooKeeper using Curator.x.discovery

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, service-discovery, apache-curator

I am trying to register a simple REST service on `int port`,
to ZooKeeper server at localhost:2181.
I checked path `ls /` using zooClient too.
Any ideas?

```
private static void registerInZookeeper(int port) throws Exception {
CuratorFramework curatorFramework = CuratorFrameworkFactory
        .newClient("localhost:2181", new RetryForever(5));

curatorFramework.start();

ServiceInstance<Object> serviceInstance = ServiceInstance.builder()
        .address("localhost")
        .port(port)
        .name("worker")
        .uriSpec(new UriSpec("{scheme}://{address}:{port}"))
        .build();

ServiceDiscoveryBuilder.builder(Object.class)
        .basePath("myNode")
        .client(curatorFramework)
        .thisInstance(serviceInstance)
        .build()
        .start();

Optional.ofNullable(curatorFramework.checkExists().forPath("/zookeeper")).ifPresent(System.out::println);
Optional.ofNullable(curatorFramework.checkExists().forPath("/myNode")).ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're not setting a path in the ServiceInstance.builder(). I think there's a bug where it silently fails when you don't set the path. So, make sure to call basePath()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept receiving `Received packet at server of unknown type 15` from Zoo Server, because of [compatibility issues](https://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility.html)

Answer (score 1):

the registration code here looks correct. In order to print registered instances the following code can be executed:

```
    Optional.ofNullable(curatorFramework.getChildren().forPath("/myNode/worker"))
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
            .forEach(childNode -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println(childNode);
                    System.out.println(new String(curatorFramework.getData().forPath("/myNode/worker/" + childNode)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

The result will be like

```
07:23:12.353 INFO  [main-EventThread] ConnectionStateManager:228 - State change: CONNECTED

48202336-e89b-4724-912b-89620f7c9954
{"name":"worker","id":"48202336-e89b-4724-912b-89620f7c9954","address":"localhost","port":1000,"sslPort":null,"payload":null,"registrationTimeUTC":1515561792319,"serviceType":"DYNAMIC","uriSpec":{"parts":[{"value":"scheme","variable":true},{"value":"://","variable":false},{"value":"address","variable":true},{"value":":","variable":false},{"value":"port","variable":true}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating your curator framework with zk34 (the version used by kafka) compatibility should fix your problem

```
    private CuratorFramework buildFramework(String ip) {
        RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3);
        return CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder().zk34CompatibilityMode(true).connectString(ip + ":2181")
                .retryPolicy(retryPolicy).build();
    }
```

Please note that curator will just try its best and some new methods (eg. creatingParentsIfNeeded (ok) vs creatingParentContainersIfNeeded (ko)) will fail.